# grep for a specific pattern anywhere in the file

Tags: bash, sed, pipe

is it possible to grep for any instance in a file in which ; is not pre and succeeded by any other character?

```
 ;
```

The problem is it does not neccessarily imply that there has to be a space to the left and right but also that ; could be the only character in a line. 
Can I somehow check whether there is more than a single ; per line in the file?
How would I do that with grep?

Comment: please learn to include small set of sample data, your expected output from that data AND your code that attempts to solve  your problem, along with any error messages and your thoughts about why it is not working. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This shows one with two ;'s on a line:

```
$ grep -E '.*;.*;.*'
```

And this will show one with ; is the only thing on a line, except perhaps whitespace:

```
$ grep -E '^ *; *$'
```

`grep -E` tells it to use extended regex syntax (`egrep` means the same thing btw) and then the rest of it is just a regular expression. `.*` matches any number of anything, zero or more of any character. So the first one has two ;'s with any number of anything between, before, or after them.

The second one matches `^` is start of line, `$` is end of line, then any number of spaces before and after the ;.

Comment: I just noticed the `sed` tag on this too. The same syntax for the regex should work in sed too.

Comment: how would I then find in a line in which there are characters besides ; but the pattern is ashkdshfks ; fjgkdf  so space ; space?

Comment: the other question was when you look for two ; on a single line then the thing is that they dont have to be next to each other ..they could be at any position on the line...

Comment: I'm not sure just what you're asking... can you show a couple more examples? Also try the two lines I put up there and tweak them a bit to see how close it is to what you need.